# PowerShell trim surname after comma or space

Tags: powershell

I'm using Get-ADUser but the requested output is tricky. I'm trying to trim a last name that has *, M. D. or *, Jr. but the Select isn't working. Also, I saw a case where a last name was Smith Jr and the request is to remove the "space Jr" so only Smith is left. Not sure how to accommodate all of these easily. Thx.

```
ForEach ($User in $Users) {

$LN = $User.Surname 
$LN1 = $LN -replace '\s',''

Select mail,telephonenumber,givenname,@{Name='surname';Expression={$LN1}} | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "|" | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Out-File "C:\Scripts\Maintenace Connection\output-test1_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).txt" -Append}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the surname cannot contain a comma or a whitespace character (not always true with real world data):

```
"Smith, Jr" -replace '(.*?)([,\s].*)','$1'
```

With your code:

```
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    $LN = $User.Surname 
    $LN1 = $LN -replace '(.*?)([,\s].*)','$1'
    $User | Select mail, telephonenumber, givenname, @{Name='surname';Expression={$LN1}} | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "|" | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Out-File ("C:\Scripts\Maintenace Connection\output-test1_{0:MM-dd-yyyy}')).txt" -f (Get-Date)) -Append}
}
```

In your original code you're looking for whitespace and replacing it with blanks; you're not saying to do anything with the other characters, so they remain.

In the updated code I'm selecting everything, but capturing everything before the space, then replacing all of it with what I captured.

Comment: Great, but how to I get it to output using the Select statement and output format? The @{} isn't working. Thx

Comment: With your select statement I think you're just not piping anything to it; so it wouldn't know what object to pick up the mail, telephonenumber, etc from; that's corrected in my answer above.  For the expression (`@{Name='surname';Expression={$LN1}}`); that works as expected.

Comment: ps. you're using `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Out-File`; you could use `Export-Csv` instead for the same effect with less code.

Comment: One last question. How do I avoid turning La Rocca (surname) into La?

Comment: @MarcGel That sir is the million dollar question. The issue is that determining what is a valid two word name, vs a name followed by a suffix, is most likely a matter of standardization. What will likely be simplest is to change it so that it searches for specific suffixes like Jr or M.D., and remove them. Then search for surnames that still contain two or more words and manually review them. Once you have made sure there are no more suffixes you can make sure new users either have no suffix when created, or a standard format is applied, like placing a comma before the suffix.

Comment: I confirm what @TheMadTechnician says; it's not a programming issue rather than a requirements one.  The best approach is to find the issues, add code to handle the common ones, and manually pick off the strays / aiming to remove the potential for such issues to recur in future.